# Putting an external page in my website by Joomla

Tags: php, html, iframe, joomla

I directed to create a travel n tours website. This website must only be a header with a menu consisting of HOTELS, CARS, AND AIRLINES. The hotels content is provided but comes from another web page. Now my question is, Can I put the entire external web page ( https://brands.datahc.com/?a_aid=143748&brandid=422829&languageCode=EN )
in my Website?

I have tried it several times by iframe. But I always get scroll bars which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Get website content using curl and create joomla plugin to display on main website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try to use php function [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$brands = file_get_contents('https://brands.datahc.com/?a_aid=143748&brandid=422829&languageCode=EN');
echo $brands; ?>
```

Or you can set iframe without the scroll bar, as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xmLroq5/)

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://brands.datahc.com/a_aid=143748&brandid=422829&languageCode=EN" height="100%"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width:100% ;
    height:100% ;
    overflow:hidden ;
}

iframe {
    width:100% ; // set your width here
    height:100% ;
    border:none ;
}
```